# Adjust y-scale in 2D graph

Tags: python, graph

I want to compare multiple graphs 2D graphs, but each graph has slightly different x-scale. So I want to modify the x-scale for all on say 1-8 units, so that they can be compared, e.g.

Graph 1:

```
X: -40.92   -50.35  -60.79  -70.23  -80.67  -90.11  -100.55 -110.00
Y: 85970    85000   85997   86131   86483   84968   85102   85825
```

Graph2:

```
X: -40.47   -50.91  -60.34  -70.78  -80.22  -90.66  -100.10 -110.55
Y: 430  481 552 585 644 5029    30256   38372
```

expected answer:
X: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
Y1: . . . . . . . .
Y2: . . . . . . . .

Where X' is new scale common to both graphs and Y1 and Y2 are values of Y for graph 1 and graph 2.

Comment: What is your expected output for this data? Please edit your question to add this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can plot your `Y` data against anything you want, so in your case, perhaps:

```
newX = range(1,len(Y)+1)
pylab.plot(newX, Y1)
pylab.plot(newX, Y2)
```

Of course, your `Y` values have quite different magnitudes, so you might need a second y-axis to see the data properly. And there are small differences between your `X` values: if these matter to you, perhaps some kind of interpolation would be useful.